# MIPS program with recursion

Tags: string, recursion, stack, mips

This is my last assignment for this semester. I need to convert a base 33 number to base 10 (this part is working) and it needs to be done with recursions (this part is not working). I wrote this code, but I am getting an error, called "Exception 5".

Why is that, and how I can fix it? I don't really know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
    .data
  userInput:    .space  700
  empty:   .asciiz "Input is empty."
   long:    .asciiz "Input is too long."
  invalid: .asciiz "Invalid base-33 number."

.text

ErrorLong:
#prints message for input that is too long
  la $a0, long
  li $v0, 4
  syscall
  j end

ErrorInvalid:
#prints message for invalid input
  la $a0, invalid
  li $v0, 4
  syscall
  j end

ErrorEmpty:
#prints message for empty string
  la $a0, empty
  li $v0, 4
  syscall
  j end

.globl main

main:
  li $v0, 8
  la $a0, userInput
  li $a1, 200
  syscall

Rid:
#takes care of leading spaces
li $t9, 32 # space
lb $t8, 0($a0)
beq $t9, $t8, Character
move $t8, $a0
j length

Character:
addi $a0, $a0, 1
j Rid

#takes care of length
length:
addi $t0, $t0, 0
addi $t1, $t1, 10
add $t2, $t2, $a0

#itertates through the array
traverse:
lb $s2, 0($a0)
beqz $s2, discovered
beq $s2, $t1, discovered
addi $a0, $a0, 1
addi $t0, $t0, 1
j traverse

#busted empty space or input that violates limit
discovered:
#if it's empty go to case for empty which outputs 
beqz $t0, ErrorEmpty
slti $t4, $t0, 5
#if it's too long, go to case for too long and print 
beqz $t4, ErrorLong
move $a0, $t2
#go to next verification process
j verify

#checks inputs
verify:
lb $s3, 0($a0)  #loads address here
beqz $s3, initial
beq $s3, $t1, initial
slti $t3, $s3, 48                 #invalid for anything below 0
bne $t3, $zero, ErrorInvalid
slti $t3, $s3, 58                 #legal input for everything less than or equal to 9
bne $t3, $zero, Move
slti $t3, $s3, 65                 #legal input for everything less than or equal to 65,  'a'
bne $t3, $zero, Move
slti $t3, $s3, 88                 #legal input for anything less than or equal to 88
bne $t3, $zero, Move
slti $t3, $s3, 97                 # invalid input, not numerical nor alphabetical
bne $t3, $zero, ErrorInvalid
slti $t3, $s3, 120                #legal input for lower case characters
bne $t3, $zero, Move
bgt $s3, 119, ErrorInvalid   # illegal input, out of range

#now I iterate again, this time to check for invalid input
Move:
addi $a0, $a0, 1 #iterates
j verify #goes to verification point

#first step of conversion, does the prerequisite work for translation 
initial:
move $a0, $t2  #moves content
addi $t5, $t5, 0  #$t5 has 0 now
add $s0, $s0, $t0  
addi $s0, $s0, -1 #decrement    
#load immediate puts values in registers to be used

Must:
addi $sp, $sp, -16
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $ra, 4($sp)
sw $ra, 8($sp)
sw $ra, 12($sp)
jal Must

ExitMust:

lw  $ra,16($sp)
lw $s4, 3($sp) 
lw $s5, 2($sp)
lw  $s6, 1($sp)
lw $s1, 0($sp)

jr $ra   #return

#li $s4, 3  #each digit
#li $s5, 2
#li $s6, 1
#li $s1, 0

translate:
lb $s7, 0($a0)   #loads digits
beqz $s7, final  #final conversion step
beq $s7, $t1, final #if branch statement is true, move to final conversion statement
slti $t3, $s7, 58  #checks for less than or equal to 58
bne $t3, $zero, Base  #OK to move forward if $t3 is not null
slti $t3, $s7, 88  #max for upper
bne $t3, $zero, Mari  #OK to go to conversion of upper characters if $t3 is not null
slti $t3, $s7, 120     #max for lower
bne $t3, $zero, Mici #OK to go to conversion of lower characters if $t3 is not null

Base:
addi $s7, $s7, -48  #conversion for regular numbers
j row

Mari:
addi $s7, $s7, -55  #conversion for upper case
j row

Mici:
addi $s7, $s7, -87  #conversion for lower case

row:  #determines which digit needs to be converted
beq $s0, $s4, one  
beq $s0, $s5, two
beq $s0, $s6, three
beq $s0, $s1, last

#first character
one:
li $t6, 35937   #values to multiply by for the power of 3
mult $s7, $t6
mflo $t7
add $t5, $t5, $t7
addi $s0, $s0, -1
addi $a0, $a0, 1
j translate

#second character
two:
li $t6, 1089   #values to multiply by for the power of 2
mult $s7, $t6
mflo $t7
add $t5, $t5, $t7
addi $s0, $s0, -1
addi $a0, $a0, 1
j translate

#third character
three:
li $t6, 33   #values to multiply by for the power of 1
mult $s7, $t6
mflo $t7
add $t5, $t5, $t7
addi $s0, $s0, -1
addi $a0, $a0, 1
j translate

#fourth character
last:
li $t6, 1    #values to multiply by for the power of 0
mult $s7, $t6
mflo $t7
add $t5, $t5, $t7
#no more need to go back to translation step


final:                  #final step
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5  #moves content to $a0 so it can be printed
syscall

#last system call of the program will end program
end:   #prints result
 li $v0, 10
```

Comment: Can you summarize what your code currently does? If you were to do this in a language of your choice, how would you do it?

Comment: Yes, it converts any given number to base 10 assuming the given number is in base 33. And I have some checks for errors like if input is too long or if it's empty

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how it works? As an aside, does this work for base 33 numbers with more than 4 digits?

Comment: No. It is max 4 digits, for anything else there must be an error message.

Comment: You appear to be running this in a simulator like SPIM or MARS. The simulator will normally tell you the address at which the exception occurred, which tells you which line of code that triggered the exception. So which line of code is it?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for replying just now. I just saw your comment. Actually it is not telling me where the error is. I am thinking I am not manipulating the stack correctly, which would make sense because I don't really know how to.

Comment: looks like you are missing code where is verify, whats in t3? main?

Comment: Yeah.. I don't remember about t3 but I don't know cause I had my program with labels alone, and it worked. I don't know how to make it work with recursion though. Can you please advise?

Comment: Help?  Anybody? The due date is approaching very fast and I don't know how to use stack to do this. Please help me.

Comment: (It is wise not to rely on one source of volunteer help on the web. Perhaps you can "cross-post" this elsewhere, though if you do, ensure that all copies of it have links to all other copies, so that someone's time is not wasted if they answer in one place while you have received help elsewhere. Also, please do not beg - nearly everyone is a volunteer here).